# Preselected value for select2 tag selectBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How would you go about having tags already being preselected in their selectbox at the time the page loads? Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<select class="selectBox operatingSystems" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Windows</option>
    <option>OSX</option>
    <option>Linux</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(".operatingSystems").select2({tags: true, tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']});
```

I'm basically trying to get it to look something like it does on the select2 documentation page where they have "orange" and "purple" preselected. From: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax [image: Preselected Tagging]

Comment: That did it! I saw examples of other people just putting only "selected" in there and I guess I didn't think to ever put true in there as well.  Thanks!

Comment: It also look as if you can do this programmatically:

`$(".operatingSystems").val(["Windows", "Linux"]).trigger("change");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select an existing option by setting the `selected` property.

```
<select class="selectBox operatingSystems" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Windows</option>
    <option selected="selected">OSX</option>
    <option>Linux</option>
</select>
```

Would pre-select the OSX option in the select box. This isn't specific to Select2, it's how you set a pre-selected option in general for select boxes (both single and multiple select).

You can do this using vanilla JavaScript by setting the `selected` property on the element.

```
theOption.selected = true;
```

Or using jQuery's `.val` method for setting the value.

```
$("select").val(["OSX"])
```

In order for Select2 and other plugins to pick up the change in value, you may need to trigger the `change` event.

```
$("select").trigger("change")
```